# Getting overflow-y:scroll to work with fixed positioning html & css

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have a Jquery tools scrollable thats set to be fixed to the bottom of the browser window.

All I want to happen is for the page to be able to scroll vertically when the browser is less then 700px high. (so no content gets hidden, as its all fixed place). This feels like it should be simple but its causing me huge headaches. js solutions are fine at this point.

Thanks in advance.

http://www.vagabondbrigade.com/staging/berns/

Comment: What are you asking, what's your problem and what's your deisred effect? Do you have a live example we can see? I understand you're frustrated, but we need some more refined details instead of a ton of code and a vague explanation. Help us to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the content that is being cut off at the top of the page, I would recommend putting top and bottom margins on your css page to the proper elements to harness their positioning.

You could do a fixed height or width for the main structure of the page and then the other elements that you want positioned, position them accordingly.

example:

/* html */

```
<div id="main_structure">
  <div id="content">
      blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

/* css */

```
#main_structure {width:100%; height:700px; margin:20px 20px 20px 20px; padding:20px;}
#content {width:200px; height:200px; padding:10px; margin:20px;}
```

Comment: I just realized I didn't answer all of your questions. If you want it to scroll to just add overflow:auto in the proper css element with a minimum height of 700px

Answer (score 0):

Playing with Firebux on your page (the link that you've provided), I've added at div.floor_items a property overflow:auto; and the problem was fixed ;)

The content was bigger that my test screen resolution, and the content wasn't all visible, but with that change, the scroll bar appeared and allow me to scroll and view the "off screen" content!

This is your solution, if that was your problem!

Comment: I'm finding that adding overflow:auto to div.floor_items adds the scrollbar, but its adding an empty scrollbar that you can't actually scroll with. I'm checking that on firefox and safari.

Comment: Wend I've been testing that, the scroll bar only appeared if the resolution was lower than the necessary to show the entire content... Never the less, if I remember your code correctly, the site structure is quite odd, and since I'm not visualizing the big picture, it's hard to solve your problem! Can't you place additional content at your development page? it would be easier to provide additional help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using css media queries
either by adding  overflow-y: scroll to html or your containing element?
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

```
@media screen and (max-height: 700px) {
       #your_element_to_scroll {overflow-y: scroll;}
}
```

This will not work in older version of IE.